# Server hardware access from PHP scripts in Apache over UNC network path

Tags: apache-2.2, php, windows-xp, network-share

I have a Windows XP Pro server running Apache 2.2, which is configured with an Alias /p that points to a UNC network path (//server/projects). Apache runs under the user Apache, which (as part of some previous troubleshooting) is a member of the Administrators group. I happen to have written up a blog post [here](http://kromey.us/2009/09/apache-on-windows-serving-files-from-the-network-150.html) that details the setup if you want more detail.

This Apache server runs a PHP application that, among other things, needs to access the server's serial ports (if you must know, it's a POS application, and yes I'm fully aware that a web app is not the ideal approach here -- wasn't my call). This works just fine from PHP scripts running off of the C drive, but scripts that live on the network server do not appear to have access to the server's hardware.

Accessing the serial ports is done like so:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('com3', 'w+');
fwrite($fh, $data_to_send);
```

Again, works just fine for files that live on the C drive, but identical files on the UNC path don't work.

I need to find a solution that will allow these PHP scripts the same access to the hardware whether they're on the C drive or pulled from a network share.

*Additional information:*

- This is a VM in VirtualBox; the network share is in fact a VirtualBox Shared Folder, which is implemented as a SMB network share. Full read/write access, and works for everything except this one thing.
- Security of the server isn't a concern -- this is a dev/testing setup that is behind 3 distinct firewalls and NAT layers (a private LAN within a private LAN within a private LAN) with absolutely no access to it through any of them.
- PHP is configured as CGI rather than an Apache module (not something I can change, since this is how this app is deployed); nonetheless, it does run under the Apache user as well.

Comment: "but scripts that live on the network server do not appear to have access to the server's hardware." <-- any specific errors that lead you to believe this?

Comment: @ErikA I don't get any specific errors, no, just that identical scripts on the C drive can talk to my serial ports, but on the network share they cannot.

Comment: It seems that this whole thing would solve itself if you stopped fighting and just used linux for this.

Comment: I'd love to, but my company develops a Windows application -- not my call.